# Create laspy file object without creating a new file

Tags: python, lidar, las, laspy

I would like to create a new `laspy.file.File` object in memory without having to create a reference `.las` file.

The basic procedure is

- read `sample.las`
- clip `sample.las` by converting the x and y coordinates into numpy arrays and processing, I now have a boolean mask of coordinates in an arbitrary polygon as `True`
- apply this mask to the original set of coordinates and return a new `laspy.file.File` object

I would like to do this without having to open a `laspy.file.File` object in write mode, which seems to be the most recommended solution. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share the entire piece of code which is relevant to the question?